# I want to understand more about structures and pointers when implementing queue

Tags: c, pointers, queue, structure, nodes

I came across this line of code when I am trying to implement Queue. May I know what does creating a structure within a structure do? Why eg. that I can use structure variable q, struct* Queue q, like `q->rear->next = address_of_node`

```
struct Node{
    int data ;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Queue
{
    struct Node *front; //what does this mean?
    struct Node *rear;
};
```

Comment: I suggest you read the chapter dealing with pointers in your beginner's C text book. `struct Node* next;` : here `next` is not a _structure within a structure_, it is a _pointer_ to a `struct Node`.

Comment: This construct could be referred to as a self-referencing struct, used to allow creation of a singly linked list of objects. (search in one direction)  [Here is an intro description](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/)  Note that the `Queue` only provides access to either the `first` _or_ `last` object in the list, just like any stack.